# sql, delete duplicate records using an ID

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-delete

So if the DOCUMENTS[image] table if employeeId 1 for example has 5 files with the same filename then delete the 4 just remain 1 file(remove the duplicate or with the same filename) and the same goes to all.

I am using mariadb

#My query to get all duplicate records

#Code

```
SELECT id, employeeId, filename, COUNT(filename) FROM DOCUMENTS GROUP BY filename
      HAVING COUNT(filename) > 1;
```

Comment: Please post a sample data set (as text) and the desired result and explain how you decided which rows should survive after deduping.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure if you're trying to select only distinct items or find out those that have duplicates.
In case you only want to select  distinct / unique values :

```
 SELECT distinct id, employeeId, filename FROM DOCUMENTS GROUP BY filename
```

I'd suggest you to move the selected unique records into a temp table and then delete the original table records and then insert the unique records from temp table back to original .

Comment: I wanted to find those duplicate files

Comment: I cannot delete the records its important , I just need to update it,

Answer (score -1):

> if employeeId 1 for example has 5 files with the same filename then delete the 4 just remain 1 file

One approach uses a `delete` statement with a self-join:

```
delete d1
from documents d1
inner join documents d2 
    on d2.id < d1.id 
    and d2.filename = d1.filename
    and d2.employeeid = d1.employeeid
```

This removes duplicates on `(employeeid, filename)` while retaining the row with the smallest `id`.

You should be able to work around the safe mode error in MariaDB by moving one condition to the `where` clause, eg the filter on `id`;

delete d1
from documents d1
inner join documents d2
on d2.filename = d1.filename
and d2.employeeid = d1.employeeid
where d2.id < d1.id

Comment: @GMB , thats an invalid syntax dude.

Comment: I am using mariadb

Comment: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY col

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin: based on this error message, I slightly changed the query. Please give it a try.

Comment: @JhonCaylog: this is valid MySQL / MariaDB syntax, what makes you think it isn't?